# Importing MYSQL query output to CSV file using Python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to export the output of a query in a MYSQL  database to  a CSV file in the local system using Python. There  are 2 issues. First of all using fetchall() I am not getting any data( The same query in database produces more than 5000 rows of data), though  I got data output initially. Secondly I would like to know the code to put the  username and password in a separate file which the user cannot access  but will be imported to this file when the  script runs.

```
import os
import csv
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
d=open('c:/Users/dasa17/Desktop/pylearn/Roster.csv', 'w')
c=csv.writer(d)
Connection = pymysql.connect(host='xxxxx', user='xxxxx', password='xxxx',
         db='xxxx',charset='utf8mb4',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor )
a=Connection.cursor()
a.execute("select statement")
data=a.fetchall()
for item in data:
    c.writerow(item)
a.close()
d.close()
Connection.close()
```